# Android: camera app breaks on ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE with crop on some phones

Tags: android, camera

The code below below requests a new picture, crops it and writes the data in a temp file. It works very well on an HTC Desire HD with Android 2.2.1.

But on a Huawei Ideos with Android 2.2 the camera application stops (the Application Camera has stopped unexpectedly) and my app continues without any picture taken. A similar problem (probably the same) has been reported by a user with EVO 4G, Android 2.3.3.

On the Ideos phone I don't see the crop box after taking the picture, so I guess that is where the camera application breaks, and I guess this may depend on device specific implementations of the camera app. Anyone has a solution?

```
         case 1:
             Uri mSavedUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(basepath + "/temp" + imgExtension));
                Intent newphoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);          
                newphoto.putExtra("crop", "true");
                newphoto.putExtra("outputX",         imageSizeX);
                newphoto.putExtra("outputY",         imageSizeY);
                if (imageAspect == 0) {
                    newphoto.putExtra("aspectX",         1);
                    newphoto.putExtra("aspectY",         1);
                }
                if (imageAspect == 1) {
                    newphoto.putExtra("aspectX",         4);
                    newphoto.putExtra("aspectY",         3);
                }
                if (imageAspect == 2) {
                    newphoto.putExtra("aspectX",         3);
                    newphoto.putExtra("aspectY",         4);
                }           
                newphoto.putExtra("scale",           true);
                newphoto.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
                newphoto.putExtra("setWallpaper",    false);
                newphoto.putExtra("output",mSavedUri);
                startActivityForResult(newphoto, NEW_PHOTO);                
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Android camera implementations are pretty different, and do not support all
the options equally. Try to remove all the irrelevant settings  from intent - they
may confuse some camera apps

My first candidates would be: noFaceDetection & setWallpaper

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. In a couple of days I will start working on the next release of the app and I will certainly try removing noFaceDetection and see what happens. setWallpaper false is, unfortunately, relevant because some phones will set the picture as wallpaper otherwise.